# python pandas separator within quote leading to error tokenizing

Tags: python, pandas, separator

I have a .csv containing data like the following:

```
....
"4", "mercedes", "BLT254", "Arkis-UDV GmbH, Berlin, Oberweg", "2007"
"5", "bmw", "SUV873", "Meier Auto", "2013"
....
```

I tried reading it by means of read_csv:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Auszug_2020.csv", sep = ",", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", quotechar = '"')
```

Every data piece is wrapped inside an " ". Within the quotes, sometimes the separator "," occurs. That's a problem! I thought I could fix this by using quoechar = '"', unfortunately it is still not working.

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 7

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
My bad! The encoding is "utf-16", I just realized. Now everything is working.
Please forgive me python pandas, I'll never say anything bad about you again.

Comment: The ```sep``` argument can accept regex expressions. Since I have not used it, I can't give you the correct solution, but perhaps if you are comfortable with regex, you can try one

Comment: I am really wondering how such an easy "problem" can be so hard to solve by python pandas. I think this is one of the most basic /standard use cases I can imagine...

Answer (score 0):

Going by the sample data that you have shared, can you try reading it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", header=None, sep='", "')
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace('"', '')
df.iloc[:,-1] = df.iloc[:,-1].str.replace('"', '')
```

I tested it as follows:

Created a sample csv file with 4 records:

```
"4", "mercedes", "BLT254", "Arkis-UDV GmbH, Berlin, Oberweg", "2007"
"5", "bmw", "SUV873", "Meier Auto", "2013"
"4", "mercedes", "BLT254", "Arkis-UDV GmbH, Berlin, Oberweg", "2007"
"5", "bmw", "SUV873", "Meier Auto", "2013"
```

Code to test:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", header=None, sep='", "')
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace('"', '')
df.iloc[:,-1] = df.iloc[:,-1].str.replace('"', '')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0         1       2                                3     4
0  4  mercedes  BLT254  Arkis-UDV GmbH, Berlin, Oberweg  2007
1  5       bmw  SUV873                       Meier Auto  2013
2  4  mercedes  BLT254  Arkis-UDV GmbH, Berlin, Oberweg  2007
3  5       bmw  SUV873                       Meier Auto  2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, the optional parameter `skipinitialspace=True` in the `pd.read_csv` method to skip spaces after seperator `,` which will produce the desired result:

```
data = pd.read_csv(
    "Auszug_2020.csv", sep=",", encoding="ISO-8859-1",
    quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: It is still: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 7